# HEX Substraction in Windows ASM Shellcode returns wrong values

Tags: windows, assembly, gdb, hex, shellcode

I'm working on some shellcoding, and have this weird result on my Windows VM. The idea is, starting from Zero, carve out some value. In this case, I need that the value is equals to: **0x50505353**

```
(gdb) print /x 0 - 0x38383536 - 0x77777777
$1 = 0x50505353
```

In Python, GDB, OSX, Linux and everything else, this operation works as expected. On the Windows VM, when I perform the PUSH on OllyDBG or Immunity the result is: **0x52535051**

So the question is, WHY? What I'm missing here?

This is the operation done in ASM:

```
AND EAX,65656565
AND EAX,1A1A1A1A
SUB EAX,38383536
SUB EAX,77777777
PUSH EAX
```

The first couple of AND transform EAX = 0x00000000. Then I can subtract from that. Just to be clear, I cannot use XOR on this test.

Comment: _"Substraction in ASM"_ Where do you do any subtraction in assembly code? I don't see that anywhere in your question.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid x86 assembly. Which assembler are you using? Looking at your question I still can't see anything related to assembly language programming. It seems to be entirely about arithmetic operations in GDB.

Comment: Sorry Michael, I just updated the question to add more details on the ASM part. Is plain x86 assembly.

Comment: Why two `AND` operations and two `SUB` operations instead of one each? That's not clear from the question. Or why you can't just use `MOV`. Anyway, why are you subtracting `36353838` instead of `38383536` in the assembly code?

Comment: Is a shellcode, due to character limitations I cant use MOV or XOR. Fixed the copy of the ASM code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not subtracting `0x38383536`, you are subtracting `0x36353838`, which gives the result you stated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just in case, i fixed the copy paste. And the problem persist.

Comment: Oh boy, instead of asking the OP for clarification someone downvotes a correct answer. Upvoted to undo the wrong. Two wrongs don't a right, but oh well...

Comment: @IInspectable that is kind, thank you, though the answer seems futile.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem. When I do the calculations outside the Debugger, forgot the small detail that in order to use them in the shellcode, I should use the same values in reverse Endian Order.

Mental note: Always remember to check the order that you are working.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score -1):

To be clear, are you saying error happens on the gdb command line as well as in your windows VM program? If gdb is giving rubbish then something is wrong with the VM.

Do you have gdb or another debugger working on the Windows VM?  I'm a little confused about your runtime environment where you are seeing the error

If you have gdb where the error is occurring then here is how to debug.

If it is the program only then use stepi and info regs to see what is going on.  The value of $eax before that last subtraction is likely the one of interest but check each instruction.  If $eax has the correct value at the push then look around $sp in memory for the value. If it is still correct then follow the return from the function and look for the corresponding pop or stack read and check the value there.  Perhaps the stack is getting corrupted before you actually print/use the value?